# Bash output command too large, can't read it!

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, cat, output

I'm having some troubles on Ubuntu 14.04 initialization, it fails to mount an SSH folder and gives me the option of a manual recovery by pressing M, displaying a command-line logged at root user for debugging the problem.

My troubles start when I try to read the `sshfs` help file and it is bigger than the screen, therefore impossible to read the cut-out part.

I managed to solve this by doing `sshfs -h >> read; nano read` but I'm wondering if there is a easiest or more elegant/right way of doing this job.

PS: I'm not at the Ubuntu terminal emulator, so it's impossible to adjust the "scrolling" tab, since it doesn't exists.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

People usually use a pager like `less` to read such a long output:

```
sshfs -h | less
```

On `less` type <kbd>H</kbd> to show help.  <kbd>Q</kbd> to quit.

Note that you might occasionally need `2>&1` to see also additional output from stderr.  For `sshfs -h` it has such an output so you'd better do that like this:

```
sshfs -h 2>&1 | less
```

Besides using a pager, on Linux text console you can scroll back/forward the screen without a scroll bar by typing <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>PgUp</kbd> or <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>PgDn</kbd>.

Comment: +1  I remember being taught that `less` is `more`.  That is how I remember.  Plus, you can scroll back through `less` where you cannot with `more`.

Answer (score 1):

Commands like these may help

```
man sshfs
sshfs -h 2>&1 | more   # or "less", if possible
```